# Why would I store filenames and paths of uploads in a database?

Tags: mysql, file-upload

Question is pretty simple but I could not find an answer.

What are the Pros and Cons for having a (mysql) database table for fileuploads in a web application?

Right now I am wondering if it is necessary at all? I could just code the paths for the uploads in config files (eg. USERNAME/PROJECT/UPLOADS/...) and scan the upload directories for filenames and filetypes if I want to do something with the files like showing an Image on the website.

What are the benefits of having a "file" table as it seems everybody uses them?

Comment: there are no pros, as you database grows it needs more respurces and with binary data it increases very quickly-

Comment: I am not talking about binary data, I mean to only store the filename, path and the time/date it was uploaded or modified

Comment: Is this question "Why would I store filenames of uploads in the database?" If so, it's because then you have a *relational identifier* for them you can use to relate them to other records, like attachments to comments.

Comment: Yes i changed the question so it becomes clearer

Comment: "I could just code the paths for the uploads in config files" - whatever works for you. However, you are often storing additional information with the uploaded image, not simply the filename: user, access perms, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 possibilities

1. a separate table is need if you have a 1:n relationship i.e  1 post many images
2. a 1:! relationship i.e. i post 1 image only, can be saved in a separate table, but is usually not, because you have to join the table and so increase the programming effort,with no gain..
3. A n:m relationship i.e. many posts share identical images , then you need a bridge table and have so 3 tables i.e post table , bridge table , image table.

So as you see depending on which relationship you have, you have only one choice in a rdms.